# `GLIBC_2.25' not found when running timedoctor 2

Tags: system-installation

I am using ubuntu 16.04. When I am trying to run "time doctor 2" app from icon, its showing nothing.
When I am trying to run in terminal, it shows error

```
timedoctor2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /home/harun/timedoctor2/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the above? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: i have same issue